# como subir express a mi servidor

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, servidor, backend

**1.** Como funciona esto del servidor, tengo un backend con node js y express y necesitaría en un futuro próximo subirlo a un servidor, ¿como se sube el backend en el servidor?.

No en cuento información concreta sobre el tema, intuyo que en el servidor se instala node y se inicializa el servidor de node pero no se si es asi como se debe hacer.

**2.** ¿existe algún servidor en el que pueda desplegar el backend, un aplicación en angular y mysql gratuita para pruebas?

necesito esto ya que también debo desarrollar una app en flutter y consumir el backend.

cualquier enlace o referencia es de ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hostear la app de Angular puedes usar App Engine de Google Cloud Platform. Para hostear la API, puedes usar App engine también, o más fácil (ya que el proceso de deploy es igual que en un ordenador) compute engine, y lo mismo para la base de datos.

Eso sería lo más sencillo si es de las primeras veces que despliegas servicios ya que como te digo es igual que cuándo lo despliegas en localhost. En cambio, sí realmente lo que estás desarrollando exige escalabilidad en cuanto a demanda de esos servicios, te aconsejo que aprendas a usar Docker y Kubernetes que ayuda al facilidad de control y a reducción de costes.

PD: Los servicios que he mencionado son muy baratos y Google te regala 300USD, por lo que tanto la fase de desarrollo y una etapa temprana de producción te lo cubre esa cantidad.

PD2: Sólo hay una cosa que hay que hacer en compute engine más que en localhost y es una especie de apertura de puertos en la máquina. Te dejo el enlace al [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls?hl=es-419) de cómo hacer el proceso (un solo comando).

Espero que te sea útil, suerte.